# Publish fields of Meteor.user to the client

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'm trying to add a custom balance field to the meteor.user collection, but I'm having problem accessing it from the client.

Event if I create a fresh project with autopublish and insecure it doesnt work. Let's say I want to publish the createdAt field of the user collection:

```
# server
if Meteor.isServer
 Meteor.publish "userData", ->
  console.log @userId
  if @userId
    Meteor.users.find
      _id: @userId
    ,
      fields:
        createdAt: 1

  else
    @ready()
  return

# client

if Meteor.isClient 
 Meteor.subscribe "userData"
```

/project/collections/user.coffee

Anyhow when I type Meteor.user() in the console of the broswer I still cant read the createdAt field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success case, your function needs to return a cursor in the client. The explicit `return` is preventing this. I'd write it like this:

```
Meteor.publish 'userData', ->
  return @ready() unless @userId
  Meteor.users.find @userId, fields: createdAt: 1
```

Comment: I solved it a few seconds before you by mistake. Thank you very much that you explained me what I did wrong (right). Anyhow I was following the official guide and converting it to coffee, why it didnt work? is it an error on the official docs or is the coffee translation?

Comment: Its a translation issue because of the way CoffeeScript does returns. If you put an explicit return in front of the find like: `return Meteor.users.find...` then it will probably work. In your code it doesn't return there, instead it gets to the end and just returns `undefined` to the caller. In CoffeeScript you generally don't want to explicitly `return` at the end of a function.

Comment: Sorry, David, why do you return the `@ready` function instead of calling it? Is it just a typo?